# How do I install Rails on Windows using Development Kit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I'm completely new to Ruby and Rails, so I'm not too confident with the install. When I typed:

```
gem install rails
```

I got a response saying I need to update the PATH and [download the Development Kit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit).

But, when I enter:

```
c:\Users\Tim\Documents\Ruby\dk.rb init
```

I get an error from Windows saying it does not recognise the file type.

Can I get an easy to understand solution?

Answer (score 1):

Per the instructions, you are supposed to type:

```
ruby dk.rb init
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to metion when I type that I get a reply:

"ruby: No such file or directory -- dk.rb (LoadError)"

Comment: Then you are probably not in the folder where you unpacked the development kit. You need to `cd` to that folder first.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fantastic tutorial [at this site.](http://installfest.railsbridge.org)  Walks you through every step for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but I suggest you try this http://railsinstaller.org/

Installing Ruby/Rails on Windows is a pain, and RailsInstaller will do all the boring work for you.

Comment: Seriously? Hm, that's weird, did you try to revert the changes you made before to see if it makes any difference? Also, just complementing Craig's answer, did you try `ruby c:\Users\Tim\Documents\Ruby\dk.rb init`? Or cd'd to that folder before using ruby dk.rb init?

Comment: Just realised my error, I didn't cd to the correct file before typing it, again I'm completely new to it so don't really know what I'm doing. I have now installed it correctly but when I type 'gem install rails' I get a repeating error: 'unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_grey.gif, skipping:", can you tell me what this means and how I fix it?

Comment: Nah, no problem, it happens. Now, google tell me that error message  is due to some kind of incompatibility between old rails version and Ruby 1.9.2+, though I don't think that's your case. I'm afraid I can't do a lot for you because I gave up developing Rails on Windows exactly because of things like that. What is the output of `ruby -v`?

Comment: The output is: "ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]", and just out of interest, what do you use now to develop on?

Comment: Ah, well, I use Fedora now, which is Linux. And as I thought, you don't have a pre 1.9.2 ruby. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. I think that if you don't wanna wait for someone more experienced at installing Rails on Windows to help you, your best bet would to try to revert and uninstall everything you installed and use the RailsInstaller or at least a different tutorial like the one Daiku provided.